# Añadir caracter a una cadena en MySQL

Tags: mysql

(ACTUALIZACIÓN)

Hola que tal? Tengo un campo en una tabla de MySQL que me guarda el siguiente contenido:

|0|0|0|0|0|0

¿Como puedo insertarle otro cero al inicio de la cadena mediante la sentencia UPDATE? para que el resultado final sea como este:

0|0|0|0|0|0|0

De antemano muchas gracias por sus aportes.

Comment: Recuerda agregar lo que has tratado o investigado, revisa [ask]. saludos-.

Comment: Basicamente seria lo mismo que te han respondido, algo asi: `update tabla set valor = concat(0, valor)` solo seria de tener en cuenta si es necesario añadir un `where` indicando que se haga solo al valor `|0|0|0|0|0|0` o si seria un update a todos los valores. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

En el select puedes concatenarle el 0 que necesitas al inicio con la funcion CONCAT()

```
select CONCAT('0',campo ) from tabla
```

donde campo es tu atributo original en la tabla

Si lo que buscas es hacer un **UPDATE en TODA la tabla** ve con:

```
UPDATE tabla SET campo = concat('0',campo);
```

Comment: Ok, se me paso comentar que esa sentencia ya la había implementado, pero creo que me explicaré mejor. lo que ocupo es que a través de un UPDATE, le agregue un caracter al inicio de dicha cadena, que previamente ya esta guardada, gracias por la contestación...

Comment: entiendo, actualice la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Bueno primero voy a imaginar que estas utilizando js luego entonces, tienes una variable que se llama "value" la cual contiene '|0|0|0|0|0|0', que es lo que deseas guardar. Para agregarle un cero solo tiene que hacer lo siguiente.

```
value = |0|0|0|0|0|0;
value = 0 + value;
```

o utilice la funcion concat de mysql concat(0, value);

teniendo en cuenta que estoy utilizando js ya que usted no específica el lenguaje que está utilizando.

si lo que explico aquí no tiene nada que ver con lo que necesita sea más explícito con su pregunta para poder ayudarle.

Comment: Ok, aclarando ciertas observaciones:
1ra: No estoy usando js, así que creo que tienes mucha imaginación...
2da: se me paso comentar que la sentencia concat(0, value); ya la había implementado, pero creo que me explicaré mejor. lo que ocupo es que a través de un UPDATE, le agregue un caracter al inicio de dicha cadena, que previamente ya esta guardada, gracias por la contestación...

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomendaría que antes de hacer el update primero almacenes en una variable el valor que deseas modificar (en este caso, $valor = '|0|0|0|0|0|0'), después puedes usar este valor para hacer la consulta: update tabla set valor = concat(0, $valor) where valor = $valor. Puedes hacer algo así, espero te sirva.